# Modelar banco de dados de um sistema de amigos

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional, uml

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde existirá uma opção para adicionar amigos,é bem simples, não é rede social, mas tem que adicionar amigo.
Tenho a tabela usuario.
Quais tabelas e quais relacionamentos tenho que criar para adicionar amigos? 
Se alguém mandar um exemplo mais simples e que funcione,mostrar quais tabelas, e quais campos, e quais relacionamentos entre si precisam. 
Obrigado

Eu achei um exemplo,acho que resolve minha situação:

1) João faz uma requisição de amizade para Maria 
- requestorId = id do Joao 
- targetId = id da Maria 
- Criar registro na tabela REQUISICAO (requestorId, targetId)

2) Listar as requisições enviadas para a Maria na página dela 
- Buscar todos os registros na tabela REQUISICAO quando o targetId for igual ao id da Maria 
- Para cada registro montar uma mensagem do tipo (Joao quer ser seu amigo - Aceitar ou não)

3) Maria recusa 
- Exclui o registro da tabela REQUISICAO.

4) Maria aceita 
- Cria registro na tabela AMIZADE (idJoao, idMaria) 
- Exclui o registro da tabela REQUISICAO.

Mas como ficariam os tipos de relacionamento, de qual para qual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meu ver é interessante armazenar o solicitante e o solicitado da seguinte forma

```
        Usuarios
----------------------------
id_usuario  |  Nome
    1       |  Joao
    2       |  Maria
    3       |  José

                                 Amigos
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
data_solicitadao | id_solicitante | id_solicitado | data_confirmacao
  01/11/2014     |      1         |     2         |     NULL
  01/11/2014     |      2         |     3         |     01/11/2014
  01/11/2014     |      1         |     3         |     02/11/2014
  02/11/2014     |      2         |     1         |     NULL
```

Eu ainda incluiria se houve recusa de amizade para controlar solicitações em série

Dessa forma, seria possível buscar todos os amigos **de um determinado usuário**

```
SELECT * 
FROM amigos 
WHERE 
  id_solicitante = :id_usuario 
  OR id_solicitado = :id_usuario 
  AND data_confirmacao  IS NOT NULL
```

E todas as solicitações que um usuário tem **pendente para aprovar**

```
SELECT * 
FROM amigos 
WHERE 
  id_solicitado = :id_usuario 
  AND data_confirmacao IS NULL
```

---

## Observaçao

Em termos de performance às vezes é melhor não utilizar o controle por data ou campo nulo e sim por um booleano indexado dependendo de qual engine for utilizar para acessar o MySql. Nesse caso seria bom ter um campo `boolean confirmado`  separado da data e indexar pelo mesmo

Ter uma flag de rejeição ou data de rejeição é uma alternativa simples e objetiva, além de otimizada de consultar pedidos rejeitados

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data_solicitadao | id_solicitante|id_solicitado|data_confirmacao|aprovado|rejeitado
  01/11/2014     |      1        |    2        |    NULL        |  False |  False
  01/11/2014     |      2        |    3        |    01/11/2014  |  True  |  False
  01/11/2014     |      1        |    3        |    02/11/2014  |  True  |  False
  02/11/2014     |      2        |    1        |    NULL        |  False |  True
```

## Nova proposta

Utilizar um único campo com a situação atual da solicitação (P Pendente, A aprovada R Rejeitada)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data_solicitadao | id_solicitante|id_solicitado|data_confirmacao| situacao
  01/11/2014     |      1        |    2        |    NULL        |    P
  01/11/2014     |      2        |    3        |    01/11/2014  |    A
  01/11/2014     |      1        |    3        |    02/11/2014  |    R
  02/11/2014     |      2        |    1        |    NULL        |    P
```

Comment: o primeiro bloco de sql é pra saber , a lista de amigos? saber todos os amigos de um determinado usuario.

Comment: No caso da rejeição o que teria q ser feito limpar algum valor?

Comment: Obrigado , valeu

Answer (score 0):

Simples, vc teria uma tabela chamada amigos que conteria o id do usuário e o id do amigo, ela seria 1 - n e em cada registro vc colocaria o id do usuário e o id do amigo então se quiser buscar pelos amigos de um usuário faria a seguinte sql:

select * from amigos where id_usuario = X

### | amigos    |

| id        |
| id_usuario|
| id_amigo  |

Comment: Ok, mas e a requsição de amizade? teria que ter uma terceira tabela com o nome requisição , como ficaria?

Comment: Eu editei minha pergunta, com um exemplo , agora queria saber como relacionalas